# Will luaL_loadfile also preload all dofile() within a lua file?

Tags: c, lua

I preload some lua file with `luaL_loadfile` and then I execute it multiple timest (it's  a server). I have some `dofile()` calls in the lua file.

Will `luaL_loadfile` also preload all `dofile()` within the lua file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `luaL_loadfile` does not execute *any* code in the file, In particular, it does not call any embedded `dofile()` or `require` or any other function call.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but you shouldn't do it that way. Instead, load the file once and execute it once as a whole (to run the code, defining the functions, etc.). Then just call specific functions multiple times.